# How to hide vertical scrollbar in wxTextCtrl?

Tags: text, wxwidgets, scroll

I'm using wxWidgets for a cross platform app. In this app, there is a text control that contains enough text to cause the vertical scrollbar to appear. However, I do not want the scrollbar to appear. There is a flag wxTE_NO_VSCROLL that works on Windows but not *nix. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to wxGTK 2.9.0 and that worked.